# Web scrape innertext vba

Tags: excel, vba, web, screen-scraping

I've tried for a long time to scrape but i've faced a problem.

I've tried to scrape both the value with getattribute.value and tried to do it with the getelementbyID/name/ClassName, but nothing helps

I need help to web scrape the innertext called '0606' from the following html-code:

```
<td width="100%" nowrap="" colspan="3">
<input name="pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityQualifier" 
type="HIDDEN" value="CPR">CPR-nr:
<input name="pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue" 
type="HIDDEN" value="0606">0606</td>
```

My code for now is:

`Dim CPR As String
CPR = IE.Document.getElementById("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue").innerText
Range("A2").Value = CPR`

I also tried this, but this returns the very first input way above my wanted input, and no matter which value I change (1) to, it errors with 91:

```
CPR= Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).getAttribute("value"))
Range("A2").Value = CPR
```

**Can anybody help me? 
any suggestions for code would help me immensly**

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the element by it's name property like below...

```
IE.document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue")
```

Comment: What did you try? InnerText or getAttribute("value")?

Comment: Both:
`Dim CPR as String
IE.document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue").getattribute("value")
Range("A2").value 
`
                                                                                                                                                                            **and with innertext**                                         
`Dim CPR as String`
`IE.document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue").innertext``Range("A2").value`

Comment: Can you share the web link if it doesn't need any login credentials and let me know what information you are trying to extract from there?

Comment: Sorry I meant to write: 
`Dim CPR as String`
`CPR = IE.document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue").innertext`
`CPR =Range("A2").value`

Comment: It needs login credentials and I cannot share them unfortunately. It's for work

Comment: Shouldn't it be Range("A2").Value = CPR ? BTW use msgbox CPR or Debug.Print CPR to see if that holds any string. What I suspect here that the web page is not loaded completely before you extracts the element from the html document.

Comment: So it would be better to declare a variable like Dim InputElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement and then set it as Set InputElement = IE.document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_Policy??HolderId_FogP_Identi??tyValue").

Comment: Then you can check with an IF condition to see if that element was set properly. like If InputElement Is Nothing Then MsgBox "The desired element was not found." Exit Sub End If. So if this msg pops up that means the element was not found in the html document.

Comment: Also declare a variable like Dim doc As HTMLDocument and after IE is navigated to the website, give enough time to load the web page, you can use Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Loop to load the page completely and then set the html document like Set doc = IE.document and use the doc later in the code instead of useing IE.document.

Comment: Im getting errorcode **"Object value not set"** when running this code. What am I missin out on?

`Dim InputElement As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set InputElement =
IE.Document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue")(0).getAttribute("value")
Range("A2").Value = InputElement`

Comment: I have the loading code inserted before the code above

Comment: This uses the early binding method, so you will need to add reference to two libraries called Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library. If you are using late biding, change all the variables to Object. The idea behind what I suggested was whenever you set a variable in code like this, you first need to check if the variable is set properly before getting any of its attribute.

Comment: I have both of Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library checked. I'm so thankful for your help btw!

Can you explain to me in another way how I check if the variable is set properly before getting any of its attribute? I'm sure if understand what you are saying correctly-

Comment: Like what have said earlier that suppose you have declared an element like InputElement and then set it like Set InputElement = IE.document.getElementsByName("pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_Policy‌​??HolderId_FogP_Iden‌​ti??tyValue"). Now you can use msgbox or debug.print to check if the element is set properly like MsgBox InputElement Is Nothing. This will return True if InputElement was not found in the html document and False if it was found.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the element and then parse the OuterHTML to retrieve the value.

```
Dim s As String
s = IE.document.querySelector("input[name=pg41_PolicyHolder_FogP_PolicyHolderId_FogP_IdentityValue]").outerHTML 
Debug.Print Split(Split(s, "value=" & Chr$(34))(1), Chr$(34))(0)
```